# Does a function local static variable prevent function inlining?

Tags: c++, inline

I'm writing an attribute shim to get the raw c-string from a library's string implementation. This specific string class, say `string_t` has members `length()` and `data()`.
When `length()  == 0` `data() == nullptr`.

Now I am using an api that doesn't like null strings so my shim returns the address of an empty string.

```
inline char const* get_safe_c_str( string_t const& str ){
    static char const empty[] = "";
    return str.length() > 0 ? str.data() : &empty;
}
```

Does my static variable prevent the compiler from inlining this function?

Comment: Btw, you can return the address of a string literal. Their lifetime is the whole program (or the lifetime of the dll, if you're dynamically loading and unloading, but that's off-piste as far as the standard is concerned, and no worse than your local static)

Comment: Really? Way cool. That's much better than the static array.

Comment: I just noticed something wrong in the code above, I'm returning the address of the array, not of the first element. This wouldn't compile since you can't convert from `char const (*)[1]`(pointer to array of char) to `char const *`(pointer to char).

Comment: @Rob: oh yeah. Oops. Pointless and misleading question removed ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not prevent inlining.  There will still be only one instance of the function-local static variable, and everywhere the function is expanded inline, that instance will be used.

Whether a particular compiler with particular options *actually* inlines such a function is another matter, and you'd have to compile your program to see what your compiler actually does, but there is no technical reason the function *can't* be inlined.

Note, however, that in your program, `return str.length() > 0 ? str.data() : "";` would also work fine; a string literal has static storage duration and exists until the program terminates.